# JavaScript XML-RPC call not executing

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, odoo, xml-rpc

I am trying to call a python method using javascript from my html file. Below is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gadget</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xmlrpc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="call()">Select</button>
<script>
function call() {
        $.xmlrpc({
            url: 'my_odoo_server',
            methodName: 'web_login',
            params: ['admin', 'i-011d151e9af5b5588'],
            success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(response)
},
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {}
        });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the xml-rpc call is not executed completely. Please help to solve this problem.

Here is console image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr52v.png)

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: I added my console image. Please check.

Comment: i am not getting any error with your code. Sending the request on my server i get a response with no issues. Sending on another though i get the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" error which is normal. Is the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" your issue?

Comment: Now i saw your addition. Your issue is CORS. Check out this resource "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS". You will have to setup your Response Server ("my_odoo_server") to allow "cross-origin" requests.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should extend the view in your base.xml file for example :

```
<t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
t t-jquery=".oe_list_buttons" t-operation="append">
    <button type="button" oe_button oe-c1>My button</button>
 </t>
```

then you call your function from js:

```
var $c_1_button = this.$buttons.find(".oe-c1");

    $c_1_button .click(function() {

            var mod=new instance.web.Model("your.model");
             mod.call("your_python_function",[params],{}).done(function(res) { });
```

Comment: I can't make any changes in my server files. I have to use javascript xml-rpc calls to call odoo login method.