# How to login Odoo with Javascript XML-RPC library

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, odoo

I am preparing a gmail contextual gadget in which I can only write javascript. And I want to login odoo using javascript.

If anyone knows how to use JavaScript XML-RPC to call Odoo login method please help me solve my problem. I am trying it from last 10 days. But didn't get success in it.

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41015011/4073812 .Here is my code